# Error building the project in Hudson

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I am trying to build a project in Hudson but it gives the following error.

> The project  (root.hudson\jobs\project\workspace\pom.xml) has 1 error
>   [ERROR]     Non-readable POM
>   root.hudson\jobs\project\workspace\pom.xml:
>   root.hudson\jobs\project\workspace\pom.xml (The system cannot find
>   the file specified).

Can someone please tell me how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [ERROR] Non-readable POM root.hudson\jobs\project\workspace\pom.xml: root.hudson\jobs\project\workspace\pom.xml (The system cannot find the file specified).

It seems your pom.xml cannot be read. Maybe it does not exists, or the user running Hudson does not have sufficient rights to read it.

With more details on the job configurations, the user running Hudson and the user rights on your pom.xml (if it does exists), I think we may be able to help you a little more :)